# Simple authorization test with RSpec & Capybara failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to test some authorization on my website using RSpec & Capybara. The idea is that an article can only be editable by ad administrator or the person who wrote the article. I'm not using any gems, just a few simple rules.

This is my spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'capybara/rspec'

describe "the authorization process", :type => :feature do
  before :each do
    @user = User.new(:id => 3, :email => 'user@example.com', :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password', :username => 'Dummy User')
    @user.save
  end

  it "does not allow a registered user to edit others' articles" do
    visit '/login'
    within("#new_user") do
      fill_in 'Email', :with => 'user@example.com'
      fill_in 'Password', :with => 'password'
    end
    click_button 'Log in'
    expect(page).to have_title 'Website Name'
    expect(page).to have_content 'Signed in successfully!'

    # Seems to be working up to here

    visit section_path('mysection')

    click_link 'Some link on the page'
    expect(current_path).to eq(my_article_path(section: 'mysection', year: 2014, month: 10))
  end
end
```

but running this returns the following error:

```
Failures:

  1) the authorization process does not allow a registered user to edit others' articles
     Failure/Error: click_link 'Some link on the page'
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:38:in `show'
```

So I look at the *articles_controller.rb* file and find:

```
34 def show
35   if @article.nil?
36     redirect_to root_path, alert: "Oops! There are no articles matching a url ending in \"#{params[:id]}\""
37   else
38     @username = @article.user.username
39   end
40 end
```

I tried using pry to see what happens right before the `@username = @article.user.username` line. It appears as if my `@article` object exists, but calling `.user` from my test returns `nil` and as a consequence, calling `.username` on that also returns nil, causing the failed test.

This works in development and production, just not in test. I'm wondering how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you create the article in your test?

Comment: I don't. Ironically though, pry shows me that the `@article` object exists when I hit the `show` method in the articles controller.

Comment: Oh I think I get it... I think I need to create the user referenced by that specific article. I will give it a try.

Comment: Yeah, that will sort it.  I'm confused as to how you have an article but never mind.

Answer (score 1):

Try to stub the `username` of the `article` so that it is not `nil` when it gets called:

```
before(:each) {allow(@article.user).to receive(:username).and_return('username')}
```